# Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response::isSuccessful()

Tags: php, response, guzzle, psr-7

So I have installed the Guzzle library version 6 according to [TeamUp calendar documentation](http://apidocs.teamup.com/?php#querying-the-teamup-api). However, when I try to run the code below I get

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response::isSuccessful()
```

code:

```
<?php
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

define('API_KEY','****ww9d5ea2b0540ba1e02c08100b0e5**');

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' => ['Teamup-Token' => API_KEY]]);
$res = $client->get('https://api.teamup.com/ks************/events?startDate=2016-08-21&endDate=2016-08-25');

if ($res->isSuccessful()) {
    echo $res->getBody();
    // {"event":{ ... }}
}
```

Shouldn't be contained in Library?
Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is no method `isSuccessful`.
By default Guzzle will throw exception if server return error

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

> A GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException is thrown for 500 level errors
>   if the http_errors request option is set to true.
>
> A GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException is thrown for 400 level errors
>   if the http_errors request option is set to true.
>
> In the event of a networking error (connection timeout, DNS errors,
>   etc.), a GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException is thrown.

Anyway, you can check the status code of the response using

```
$res->getStatusCode();
```

Answer (score 1):

The [upgrade notes from Guzzle 5.0 to Guzzle 6.0 say](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/a0d75173c8553b4281c8319333d9ee90e4656ed1/UPGRADING.md):

> GuzzleHttp\Message\Response::isSuccessful() and other related methods have been removed. Use getStatusCode() instead.